# Codeigniter image upload

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

I have a problem that if the user doesn't select an image he can press the "submit" bottom and then it edits the name in the database to nothing (because there is no image) so his profile picture is blank and I don't want that. I want to show a error that the user didn't select an image.

My other problem is when the user uploads a new image how can I delete the old one from the server?.

Here is my of my code:

view

```
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('profil/uploadImg'); ?>
    <div style="float:none; margin-bottom:5px;" id="profil_billed">
        <img width="200" height="200" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/users/<?php echo $query->profile_picture; ?>" alt="">
    </div><!-- profil_billed -->
    <?php echo form_upload('userfile'); ?><br><br>
    <?php echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload billed', 'class=bottom'); ?>
    <?php echo form_hidden('username', $this->session->userdata('username')); ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

model

```
function addProfileImg()
{
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
        'max_size' => 2000,
        'encrypt_name' => true
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

    $config = array(
        'source_image'    => $image_data['full_path'],
        'new_image'       => $this->gallery_path . '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ration' => true,
        'width'           => 200,
        'height'          => 200,
        'encrypt_name'    => true,
        'max_size'        => 2000
    );

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();


    # Ret profil billed navn #

    //$data = $this->upload->data('file_name');
    //print_r($data);

    $file_array = $this->upload->data('file_name');
    $profilBilledNavn['profile_picture'] = $file_array['file_name'];

    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->update('users', $profilBilledNavn);


}
```

controller

```
function uploadImg()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('upload', 'upload',
        'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'userfile',
        'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() != true)
    {
        $this->load->model('profil_model');
        $this->profil_model->addProfileImg();
        redirect('profil/indstillinger/'.$this->session->userdata('username'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CI's file uploader has some basic error handling - [from the docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

```
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) // here
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
```

I imagine if the file is empty it will error.

As for deleting the image, I imagine you have the path of the image stored in the database:

You can use [`unlink()`](http://www.php.net/unlink):

```
$path = '/path/to/my/img/upload/001.jpg'; // wherever you store this value.

unlink($path); // returns true/false on success
```

Comment: @Ross thanks, but i got this error :S Fatal error: Call to a member function do_upload() on a non-object in

Comment: @Ross i have try this now http://pastebin.com/LT3r60QC but it echo "error" all the time if i dont upload and if i upload a image :S can you see whats wrong?

Comment: it says Upload trial does not appear to be valid. with the display_errors function

Comment: @ole upload trial? perhaps you mean upload path? check that's valid. do a `print_r($data)` and `print_r($error)`;

Comment: @Ross yes path :p, i found the error.. its beucase i cant load the library 2 times.. in my model file i use this to set the settings i want the image to be $this->load->library('upload', $config); (load number one)... and in my controller i use this: if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) so i need to load the "upload library again in the controller (load number 2) and then it get bugged cause you cant load the same 2 times.. so do you know what i can do?

Comment: try reading the docs - `// Alternately you can set preferences by calling the initialize function. Useful if you auto-load the class:
$this->upload->initialize($config);`

Comment: @Ross ye i have try that now but it still says the same :S thats weired

Comment: i found out its this that give the error if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) i take the ! off it works fine and upload the image, but if i click on the submit button without selecting a image it update the database with nothing so it cant find the image and then dont show a image, and that why i want to check if the user have slected a image

Answer (score 0):

```
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                       // error ..show it to user

        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                        // save to db

        }
```

and for deleting 
you have to use `unlink()`
and then you may also have to delete it from db.
you can use a simple getwhere ..
example :

```
$config['query'] = $this->db->get_where('images','some id here may be');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with javascript

> function validate() {
>
> var extensions = new 
>   Array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png","bmp");
>   
>   // Alternative way to create the array
>   var extensions = new Array(){
>   extensions[1] = "jpg"; extensions[0] =
>   "jpeg"; extensions[2] = "gif";
>   extensions[3] = "png"; extensions[4] =
>   "bmp"; var image_file =
>   document.form.image_file.value; 
> var
>   image_length =
>   document.form.image_file.value.length;
>   var pos = image_file.lastIndexOf('.')
>   + 1; var ext = image_file.substring(pos,
>   image_length); 
> var final_ext =
>   ext.toLowerCase(); 
> for (i = 0; i <
>   extensions.length; i++)
>  {
>   if(extensions[i] == final_ext) {
>   return true; 
> } 
> }
>  alert("You must
>   upload an image file with one of the
>   following extensions: "+
>   extensions.join(', ') +"."); return
>   false; 
> }

that way you wont need to do a request to the server.

** this code is from http://www.bitrepository.com/validating-an-image-upload.html